# Bootstrap Dropdown Displaying Same Information

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a nav bar using the bootstrap dropdown feature.https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/ Each button in the navbar shows the same information in the dropdown menu. Example: The exercises button shows assignments and the assignment button shows assignments as well.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Assignments
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://ec2-3-17-178-150.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/home.php">Assignment 1: PHP Page</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Assignment 2: My SQL Form <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Assignment 3: JavaScript Validation/code <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                </div>
            <!--Exercise dropdown info-->
            
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Exercises
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://ec2-3-17-178-150.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/HelloWorld.php">CE01: Hello World<i>Coming Soon</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE02: Days of the Week <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE03: Using Forms and  $_POST <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE04: Story Idea Generator <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE05: Workbench Setup <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE06: Adding and removing from Database <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE07: Forum Database <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE08: Monster Manager <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE09: Adding and removing from Database <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE010: JavaScript Objects <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE011: JS Control <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE012: Session Control <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE013: Login<i>(Coming Soon) </i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE014: Shopping Cart <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                </div> 


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score -1):

You have given same id to both dropdown menu , change it

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

   <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Assignments
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://ec2-3-17-178-150.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/home.php">Assignment 1: PHP Page</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Assignment 2: My SQL Form <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Assignment 3: JavaScript Validation/code <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Exercises
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
 
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://ec2-3-17-178-150.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/HelloWorld.php">CE01: Hello World<i>Coming Soon</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE02: Days of the Week <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE03: Using Forms and  $_POST <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE04: Story Idea Generator <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE05: Workbench Setup <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE06: Adding and removing from Database <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE07: Forum Database <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE08: Monster Manager <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE09: Adding and removing from Database <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE010: JavaScript Objects <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE011: JS Control <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE012: Session Control <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE013: Login<i>(Coming Soon) </i></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CE014: Shopping Cart <i>(Coming Soon)</i></a>
  </div>
</div>



  </body>
</html>
```